# Logstash - Split characters in string into 2 fields

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have Logstash reading in a CSV file, which contains a field `my_id`, and is an 8-digit string made up of numbers.

I'd like the output file to have 2 fields in place of `my_id`. One named `id_start` which will be the first 6 digits and `id_end` which will be the last 2 digits.

example: my_id: `12345678` would become id_start: `123456` and id_end: `78`

I'm very new to Logstash but I've been reading around and I think I need to use a `grok` filter to do this - my attempt to create the first field so far has not worked:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["id_start", "(?<my_id>.{6})"]
  }
}
```

I'm also finding it quite hard to find good examples on this sort of thing, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ruby](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) filter and write custom ruby code like:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
        event['id_start'] = event['my_id'][0..6]
        event['id_end'] = event['my_id'][6..8]
        "
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is different for Logstash 5.x+, they have implemented getters and setters and restricted access to the variables.

```
ruby {
  code => "
      event.set('[id_start]', event.get('[my_id]')[0..6])
      event.set('[id_end]', event.get('[my_id]')[6..8])
      "
}
```